# (Unity) what happens if i get a transform.position of a nested object

Tags: unity, navmesh

Okay so here is the example

You have a plane at position `0,0,0` with a scale `15,1,15` (for demonstration)

Now you have a parent object for the sake of simplicity lets call it `parentObject` this parent object has the following position: `7,25,26` The parent **DOES NOT** have a mesh and is thereby an empty `gameobject`

The parent has a `child` `gameobject` **Here the issue starts** the `child` has a transform position at `5,-25,30` however this objects `transform.position` is relative to the parent

last take our `agent` i know set him to go to `childObject.transform.position` will he then move correctly to the object or will he, in fact, move to the position that is relative to the `parent` object?

I know this might seem a bit messy but the general question is if i tell an agent to go to a gameobject that is a child of another object using `transform.position` will he go to the place we would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform.position` returns the position of an object in world-space coordinates, as in, where the object is in relation to the centre of the world. So basically, it "adds up" all transformations (including position) from all of its parents, to find out its final position.

`transform.localPosition` gives the local position of the object, as in, where the object is in relation to its parent (The value you see in the inspector).

So if `my_obj.position` returns `(0, 0, 0)` that means `my_obj` is located at the centre of the world. If `my_obj.localPosition` returns `(0, 0, 0)`, then `my_obj` is located on the exact same location of its parent.

When moving objects around, if you use `transform.position` would give expected results, `NavMeshAgent`s in Unity expect world-space coordinates, unless otherwise specified in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. is there a better way to move your agents than transform.position?`

Comment: "Better" for what objective/goal/criteria, @MarcRasmussen? Is there a specific problem you've encountered with transform.position that you'd like strategies to overcome?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen If you want to move a `NavMeshAgent` you can do so using `SetDestination(targetPosition)` or some other method from its API. You can use `transform.position` to get the position of other objects to pass to the `SetDestination`.